# In Branch.io, How to post a Deep-link with query parameters in facebook

Tags: android, facebook, deep-linking, branch.io

I´m having problems with a deep-link (using appending query parameters) in a facebook post. When I click, the app just opens but the data from appended parameters is not returned in the referringParams when i have the app already installed (Android App). I tried the solution below without success..

https://github.com/BranchMetrics/Android-Deferred-Deep-Linking-SDK#important-migration-to-v145

The same cenario works for ios.

Does anyone know how can i resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

This is likely an issue with the way you've set up sessions. I recommend you do the following:

- Inside your Application class, make sure inside `onCreate`, you're calling `Branch.getAutoInstance(this)`.
- Make sure you call `Branch.initSession` inside the deeplink activity that a user goes into from Facebook.
- Inside `onNewIntent`, make sure that there's a `?link_id` appended to the end, as Branch wont know which link to return without that.